# ¿Cómo mostrar un gif en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en C# en la cual, existe un botón de sincronización, este sincroniza los datos entre el servidor local y el remoto. La acción tarda un minuto en promedio y quisiera mostrar un gif con la leyenda de "sincronizando". He intentado de varias formas pero ni una me ha servido. Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Intenta checando la información de la siguiente pregunta, o al menos publica el codigo del proceso donde quisieras mostrarlo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210922/how-do-i-get-an-animated-gif-to-work-in-wpf

Comment: Intenté eso pero no me funcionó, el Gif se mostró hasta que el proceso se terminó, algo así como si fuera de efecto retardado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte de este proyecto, antes se encontraba en Codeplex, pero ya migraron a Github [WpfAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif)

Instalación via Nuget:

```
Install-Package WpfAnimatedGif
```

Uso:
Importa el namespace

```
xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
```

Y usa el tag `Image` con el atributo `gif`

```
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="migif.gif" />
```

**EDIT**

Basado en tu comentario

Deberias usar [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  (u otra forma asincrona), para invocar tu proceso, ya que tu pantalla parece que se "congela" debido que tu proceso se esta ejecutando en el hilo de la vista

Ejemplo:

```
    private BackgroundWorker worker;        

    private BackgroundWorker GetWorker()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        return worker;
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //aqui acabamos
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //ejecuta tu proceso
    }
```

Comment: Y cómo lo uso para que se muestre mientras otro proceso está ejecutándose? Porque lo intenté y se muestra hasta que el proceso terminó.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, vi tu comentario en la pregunta despues de publicar esta respeusta

Comment: Me parece muy buena respuesta. En cuanto tenga tiempo de probarlo te califico. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Muy sencillo, consta de 2 partes para que el gif se muestre al inicio y no se lance al terminar:

1. Usa el package 'WpfAnimatedGif' que indica jasilva
2. No uses BackgroundWorker, usa llamadas async

//Sincroniza local con DB

```
private void Sincronizar()
{
    var tsk = SincronizarAsync();
}
```

//Método async para sincronizar

```
async Task SincronizarAsync()
{
    MostrarGifDeCarga();
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => MiObjeto.CargarSusDatosDesdeBD());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error sincronizando: " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {       
        //esto lo puedes colocar después del await si no quieres usar 'finally'
        RaisePropertyChanged("MiObjeto");
        OcultarGifDeCarga(); 
    }   
}
```

Los métodos 'MostrarGifDeCarga' y 'OcultarGifDeCarga' los puedes colocar en una Interface para usarlos desde cualquier vista.

Y con esto funciona tal como quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mostrar un mensaje cuando se ejecuta un proceso deberias realizar el mismo usando `thread` o sea ejecutarlo en un proceso separado.

Sino lo realzias en un proceso separado la imagen se bloqueara.

[Threads in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1c8574/threads-in-wpf/)

Si lanzas la tarea en un thread podrias mostrar el gif mientras se ejecuta.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        //aqui muestras el gif

        Thread thread = new Thread(Proceso);  
        thread.Start();  
    }  

    private void Proceso()  
    {  
        //aqui realizas el proceso que demora 1min  
    }
```

Tambien podrias usar el `BackgroundWorker`, al ser un componente tienes eventos dodne poder ocultar el gif cuando termine el proceso

Comment: Existen formas más elegantes que crear tu proprio Thread. Al final, estas formas también utilizarán threads detrás de las escenas pero te evitan ese trabajo a tan bajo nivel. Un ejemplo de eso es `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza claro por eso mencione al final el BackgroundWorker, pero tambien se podria usar Task, puse un ejemplo simple para remarcar que se necesita lanzar el proceso en un thread para que el gif se mueva