# ¿Como mostrar una imagen antes de finalizar un evento? - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy tratando de hacer un loading para un formulario de inicio de sección. Le he puesto un gif animado para hacer el efecto de loading.

Lo que pasa es que cuando utilizo la propiedad `loading.Visible = true` esta no se hace visible hasta que el evento `click` finaliza.

Aquí esta el código.

```
private void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loading.Visible = true;
    if (ConectarBaseDatos())
    {
        OpenFormulario();
        this.Close();
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Usuario o contraseña, incorrectos");
    loading.Visible = false;
}
```

La Base de datos tarda de 3 a 6 segundos a responder en la función `ConectarVaseDatos()` pero el gif no se hace visible hasta que el evento finalize.

Alguien podría decirme ¿Como podría hacer esto?

Comment: haciéndolo desde un nuevo hilo. ¿lo intentaste?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo No se mucho sobre multi procesos. XD

Comment: xD no es tarde para aprender, se me hace lo más sencillo que podrías hacer para dicha tarea

Comment: Lo mejor como te indican es con un hilo aparte, no es muy dificil, puedes usar la clase BackgroundWorker

Comment: creo que la función `conectarBaseDatos()` es la que esta pausando el programa. creo que podría utilizar una función `async` para conectarme a la base de datos?.

Comment: Si el resultado que esperas es que la imagen gif se vea con animación mientras se produce la función de la DB deberás ejecutarla en otro hilo, ya que si se ejecuta en hilo principal del programa el GIF detendrá su animación, recuerda que el UI del programa se encuentra en el hilo principal y todo lo que derive en procesamiento en el mismo lo detendrá.

Comment: Esta es la misma pregunta pero con WPF. Espero que te sirva de ayuda:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4704/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-un-gif-en-wpf/4705#4705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A menos que estés usando una versión más antigua de .NET (antes de .NET 4.5), te recomiendo usar el `Task` usando la sintaxis `async/await`. Esto permite que el flujo del código mantenga su claridad, pero logra el objetivo. Nota cuan mínimo son los cambios en comparación a tu código original:

```
private async void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loading.Visible = true;
    if (await Task.Run(() => ConectarBaseDatos()))
    {
        OpenFormulario();
        this.Close();
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Usuario o contraseña, incorrectos");
    loading.Visible = false;
}
```

Los cambios son solamente dos:

1. Agregar el keyword `async` en la firma del método `btnIniciarSesion_Click`.
2. Reemplazar `ConectarBaseDatos()` por `await Task.Run(() => ConectarBaseDatos())`

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la forma de hacerlo.

```
private void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   loading.Visible = true;
   Task.Run<bool>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectDataBase();
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result)
            {                   

                if (message == "")
                {
                    lblBienvenido.Text = "Bienvenido\n" + Usuario.Nombre + " " + Usuario.Apellido;
                    ptbLoadin.Visible = !(lblBienvenido.Visible = true);
                    this.Refresh();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
                    MDIPrincipal mdip = new MDIPrincipal();
                    this.Hide();
                    mdip.Text += " - ( " + Usuario.Tipo + " )";
                    mdip.Show();
                }
                else if (Usuario.Tipo != "Admin") FrmLogin_Load(null, null);
                else this.Close();

            }
            else resetForm();
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```